# NHibernate An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I've seen this question a lot but can't find a solution for the problem I'm seeing. I have taken over a project from a Dev that left which doesn't help as I'm not familiar with the domain.

When I try to run the project I get the following:

An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory.
* Database was not configured through Database method.

The inner exception states "Tried to add property 'StartDate' when already added." Which I'm starting to think is a red herring.

Can anyone tell me what I should look for to fix this?

Kind regards,

Daniel

Comment: Did you also check inheritance hierarchies?

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping the StartDate property twice, for example:

```
public class Order 
{
    public virtual DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}

public class OrderMap() 
{
    public OrderMap() 
    {
        Table("Order");

        Map(x => x.StartDate, "start_date");
        Map(x => x.StartDate, "start_date");
    }
}
```

Just remove the second mapping and your code should work.

Comment: Hi, I've searched through the entire project for StartDate and not found any duplicates. It's a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The NHibernate version we're using is not compatible with Visual Studio 2015! Complete red herring there was no duplicated StartDate! Installed Visual Studio 2013 site works like a charm. Wasted a day on this one.

Comment: It is not Entity Framework :) (that used to effectively block some features on older versions of Visual Studio). I think you should double check that, as I do not see why VS version should impact your application behavior - provided that you have not changed any references nor .NET framework version.

Comment: Hi @mkarczewski, I found this information which is what lead me to try VS2013 which works perfectly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33160816/nhibernate-could-not-resolve-property-only-in-visual-studio-2015-with-a-leftou